# Making relative line numbers behave well with folds?

Tags: org-mode, code-folding, line-numbers

**Context:** I have relative line numbers displayed in emacs. If there is a fold (for example: in org-mode), these relative numbers appear to "jump". For example if I'm on line 0 over a fold, emacs could show me that the next line visible is "50 lines" below me instead of 1 line below me.

**The problem:** This is causing issue with line jumping behavior. Say I want to type "50j" (in evil mode) to move 50 absolute lines down; if I do this, my cursor jumps 50 **visible** lines down, so that my cursor overshoots my target.

**Question:** Is there a way to either:

1. Make line jumping absolute-relative as opposed to visible-relative (so that typing "50j" moves 50 absolute lines down, as opposed to 50 visible lines down)?
2. Make relative line numbers along the side of the screen be visible-relative as opposed to absolute-relative?

**EDIT:** I'm running emacs 25 with spacemacs config, getting relative line numbers via `dotspacemacs-line-numbers 'relative`.

Comment: There are various ways to show line numbers. Please state how you are getting line numbers, and mention your Emacs release.